# ng2-highcharts in angular2 display when button click

Tags: angular

I'm using `ng2-highcharts` in Angular2, its displaying properly by default, 
using this `<div [ng2-highcharts]="chartOptions"></div>`

I want to display, when button click, do not load by default

for example:

```
<td id="showReport" (click)="showChart($event)">45</td>
```

Comment: post your trying

Answer (score 0):

Just load your chart option on button click, thats it

```
    <chart [options]="chartOptions" (load)="saveChart($event.context)">
          <series (hide)="onSeriesHide($event.context)">
            <point (select)="onPointSelect($event.context)"></point>
          </series>
        </chart>

    this.chartOptions;

    this.options = {
        title : { text : 'angular2-highcharts example' },
        series: [{
            name: 's1',
            data: [2,3,5,8,13],
            allowPointSelect: true
        },{
            name: 's2',
            data: [-2,-3,-5,-8,-13],
            allowPointSelect: true
        }]
    };

addPoint() {
      this.chartOptions = this.options;
      this.chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.random() * 10);
      this.chart.series[1].addPoint(Math.random() * -10);
    }
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5FI0S40gl8qJV2Ke7gc?p=preview)